# Generating a htmlwidget instead of a Shiny.tag with streamgraph

Tags: r, r-streamgraph

I recently made a streamgraph using the streamgraph package and I'm unable to save the graph as an "htmlwidget". It's currently a "Shiny.tag" and converting it to an htmlwidget would help me add it to a static webpage. Is there a way to change this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use "sg_title" to add a title to your stream graph, it will cause the stream graph to render as a shiny.tag instead of an htmlwidget.